# What is the use of access token of dynamically created device in Thingsboard?

Tags: integration, thingsboard

After the integration of Thingsboard with Thingsnetwork (TTN), when device sends data for the first-time, Thingsboard dynamically generates devices. So device just sends data and Thingsboard will display data on dashboards. Where we use access tokens? Or do we need to use the access token of dynamically generated devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to use access tokens in this case.

When devices are connected to the ThingsBoard via integrations (TTN integration in your case) - they are automatically registered in the ThignsBoard and you do not need to explicitly manage the authentication process.
The reason is that authentication is performed on the integration level (the link between TTN and the thingsBoard).